# How can I find sum of contiguous sequences of elements in a list?

Tags: python, list

I need to write a function that given a list of integers `L`, it returns `True` if the list contains a consecutive sequence of values whose sum is `n`, and `False` otherwise.

Let's say my list is: `L = [2,2,4,4,0,0,2,8]` and `n` = 3.
The function should return `False` because there are not consecutive values summing up to 3.

**requirement: Python's modules are not allowed**

I tried with:

```
def consecutive(L,n):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(L)):
            if sum(L[i:j+1])==n:
                return True
    return False
L = [2,2,4,4,0,0,2,8]
consecutive(L,3)
```

This is partially working because when I set `n=12`, it returns `True`. I understand there is something to fix with slicing, but I can't find out what it is.

Comment: Why do you say this is only *partially* working?  It appears to me that you have a solution here.

Comment: Also, I'm unclear as to your question.  What input do you want from us?

Comment: Are you guaranteed anything about the list values?  In particular, can there be negative values?

Comment: The output's functions is just partially correct (e.g with n=3, n=10). Assuming n=12 the output should be False, but my function is outputting True. I would like to know what is going wrong.

Comment: The first few elements sum to 12: 2+2+4+4, plus one or two 0's.

Comment: That's perfect. But I was thinking I set up my function to sum up each couple of elements starting from the first (e.g. `sum(L[ 0: 1+1])`, `sum(L[ 1: 2+1])`,             `sum(L[ 2 :3+1])`. I understand it's not working like that and I am here asking some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is simple: in this situation, **the range must be len+1**, otherwise it will fail in fringe cases. Working code is:

```
def consecutive(L, n):
    for i in range(len(L)+1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(L)+1):
            s=sum(L[i:j])
            if s == n:
                print(i,j,s,'TRUE')  #DEBUG: remove when done
                #return True         #uncomment this to reintegrate
            else: print(i,j,s)       #DEBUG: remove when done

    return False

L = [2,2,4,4,0,0,2,-3]
consecutive(L,3)
```

better yet, in your example, you didn't show negative numbers. If you have no negatives, you can make the code more efficient by skipping the loop when it exceeds your search value, n:

```
def consecutive(L, n):
    for i in range(len(L)+1):
        for j in range(i+1,len(L)+1):
            s=sum(L[i:j])
            if s == n:
                print(i,j,s,'TRUE')     #DEBUG: remove when done
                #return True            #uncomment
            elif s > n:
                print(i,j,s,'too big')  #DEBUG: remove when done
                break
            else: print(i,j,s)          #DEBUG: remove when done

    return False

L = [2,2,4,4,0,0,2,1]
consecutive(L,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The naive way would be to loop through each starting potential starting point (each index) and each window size (any number from 0 to the length of the list):

```
def consecutive(L, n):
    for i in range(len(L)):
        for window_size in range(len(L)):
            if sum(L[i:i + window_size]) == n:
                return True
    else:
        return False
```

Note this could easily be improved, starting with not double checking the same windows multiple times (e.g., if the list is length 3, then `L[2:4]` and `L[2:3]` would be the same thing).